# Macbook Air Early-2015 Service Recommended Warning

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, power-management

I have a Macbook Air Early-2015 model since 2017.

Like 4 or 5 months ago, I updated from High Sierra to Mojave. Initially there was no problem. But after a few weeks my Macbook started to shutdown suddenly at about %15 (in changes time to time, sometimes it can be 5%). And when it is closed, I couldn't open it without connecting charge cable.

Because of the quarantine I stuck at home and using it while charger is connected, even it has 100% charge, but not for too long like 1 month or so. But I don't think that's the reason.

Anyway. I controlled battery health with coconutBattery and it was about 80-85%, I can't remember clearly, maybe even more, but I'm sure it was not less. Then I did a research and found SMC & NVRAM reset. I did those resets and calibrate the battery by charging to 100% and draining until it shuts down itself.

The sudden shutdown problem seemed to be solved, but after a few days the Service Recommended warning started to appear. And when I checked with coconutBattery, it said 55% battery health. Still same value with small changes. I mean, how this can be possible? The cycle count is not even close to its limit, it just have 350 cycle. I have friends who has same computer for more than 5 years and more than 800 cycle without changing the battery and their batteries' health are much better than mine.

It seemed like a software problem to me. Before try formatting or downgrading to High Sierra I just wanted to ask you. Thus I won't waste my time by backing up and formatting if it won't make a difference.

Now I have to charge it like every 4-5 hours. And I realized that sometimes the battery percentage is going up. Like, I am looking the percentage and it shows 65% and I am going back to my work, write something in Word etc. 5 minutes later when I check that again, it shows 66%. That's odd.

I don't want to buy a new battery, I can't spend that much money right now.

I apologize for the long text, I just wanted to explain everything :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Batteries have an *expected* life of  3 to  5 years and yours is at the upper end of that range now. Age is actually more important than cycles. Can you have batteries that last 7 or even 10 years with more than 1000 cycles?  Sure, but batteries can also die in  3 years and have only a couple hundred cycles. Theres no "minimum"  cycle  count that you're guaranteed.  Unfortunately, it has to be replaced.

Comment: "I won't waste my time by backing up..."  Backing up is never a waste of time.  This should be something you do on a regular basis.

Comment: Thanks Allan! I know they have an expected life span but as I mentioned earlier, I have some friends who bought same model before me and still have better health. And maybe you just missed that point: the health was about 80-85% than in about 2 or 3 days it decreased to 55%. No matter how old the battery is, I do not think that such a drop will occur in such a short time. And I backup my important files regularly. However there are files that is not so important but needs to be copied before formatting.

Comment: I linked several answers so that each of your points would be covered.  Going from 80-ish to 50-ish percent sounds like a failing cell and there's no way to really test it unless you take it into a proper lab where it can be analyzed - and yes...what you're experiencing can happen without warning.  These are *chemical reactions* (not mechanical) and the SEI layer between the "plates" (anode, cathode, separator, etc. ) and/or cells can build up too quickly due to a defect or failure causing a sudden drop in capacity.  How your friends battery performs has no relation to how yours will perform.

Comment: OK, thank you so much for your help. Seems like I'd better start saving money for battery.

Comment: I advise folks to assume you'll need a battery by year 3 and budget for it. If you go 4, 5,  or more years then you came out ahead. If not, you were prepared for it.

Comment: Thanks again. I have one more question for you. Should I buy the battery from 3rd party sellers or just give it to Apple service and ask them to change the battery? I can change it too, it's a simple process but what I'm asking is, will 3rd party/non-Apple batteries (I know Apple doesn't make batteries, for example, my original battery is made by SMP) damage my mainboard or something? There is not so much price difference but of course, Apple service is more expensive. If there is no problem in purchasing 3rd parties, to what should I pay attention when buying?

Comment: Apple  will change the whole top case ( keyboard, trackpad, battery, etc.)  whereas independent ships will just do the battery.  Get a quote from both.  To me, there’s no need to replace perfectly good components; I’d get just the battery, but you must decide for yourself what you’re most comfortable with. If you go 3rd party, try to get a warranty of at least 18 months. Longer warranty means the vendor is confident it won’t  have to be replaced in that time frame. Apple only gives 12 months, btw.  I’ve had 18 month batteries last 36+ months where 12 month batteries barely last 18.

Comment: Thank you very much for giving explanatory answers to all my questions. Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

Have you contacted Apple to get a quote on the battery? They can run diagnostics remotely and send a box. It’s worth the time in case they want to service the battery due to a service program at no cost to you. Once they ask for service, it could be a short time till it stops working entirely. Or you could run on wall power at slower speeds until you want to replace or repair it.

Comment: Yes I got in touch with them and all they said was "We have nothing to do. Batteries' performances can decrease in time even they don't complete their cycles." Yes I know that but it's not an old Macbook, it's just 3 years old. But they did not run any diagnostics. Maybe I should call them again and want a remote diagnostics. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Yes. Ask them to diagnose the battery and quote a repair. You don’t have to pay once they estimate it.